# Merging two sorted linked lists in the most efficient way

Tags: java, linked-list

Recently I came across this problem.I'm unable to solve it and it is gnawing at me.My code does not work and I  cannot understand where I am going wrong.

```
//Program to merge two sorted linked lists.

public class LLMergeSort{
static Node head1;
static Node head2;
static Node newHead;

static class Node{
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int d){data=d;next=null;}
}

public static void merge(Node head1,Node head2,Node newHead){

    Node curr1 = head1;
    Node curr2 = head2;

    while(curr1!=null && curr2!=null){
        if(curr1.data<curr2.data){
            Node new_node = new Node(curr1.data);
            new_node.next = newHead;
            newHead = new_node;
            curr1 = curr1.next;
        }
        else{
            Node new_node = new Node(curr2.data);
            new_node.next = newHead;
            newHead = new_node;
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        }
    }

    if(curr1==null){
        while(curr2!=null){
            Node new_node = new Node(curr2.data);
            new_node.next = newHead;
            newHead = new_node;
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        }
    }
    else if(curr2==null){
        while(curr1!=null){
            Node new_node = new Node(curr1.data);
            new_node.next = newHead;
            newHead = new_node;
            curr1 = curr1.next;
        }
    }
    print(newHead);
}

private static void print(Node newHead){

    Node curr = newHead;
    System.out.println("Linked list after merging both the lists : ");
    while(curr!=null){
        System.out.print("["+curr.data+"]->");
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    System.out.print("NULL");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    LLMergeSort ll1 = new LLMergeSort();
    ll1.head1 = new Node(11);
    ll1.head1.next = new Node(10);
    ll1.head1.next.next = new Node(8);
    ll1.head1.next.next.next = new Node(6);

    LLMergeSort ll2 = new LLMergeSort();
    ll2.head2 = new Node(18);
    ll2.head2.next = new Node(15);
    ll2.head2.next.next = new Node(9);
    ll2.head2.next.next.next = new Node(7);
    ll2.head2.next.next.next.next = new Node(2);

    LLMergeSort ll3 = new LLMergeSort();

    ll3.newHead = null;

    merge(head1,head2,newHead);

    }
}
```

I am new to coding so if anyone feels that my programs are not up to the standard,then please tell me.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your code does. Maybe describe the specific problem you are trying to solve. However, `next.next.next.next` is certainly not up to standard.

Comment: Upon running the code,I get the two linked lists attached with each other with no operations done upon them.I cannot understand where the merge operation has gone wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I am not a student.do you want my credentials ? I am from electrical engineering background trying to get into coding.I code part time.So any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Fair enough.  Most of the points in the post still apply though.

Comment: @MayankGupta *"trying to get into coding"* That means you're in the process of *learning* to code, aka you *study* code (in your free time, perhaps), aka you are a *student* of programming. You don't have to go to school to be a student. Homeschooling, self-teaching, ... still makes you a **student**.

Comment: yes,by transitive property i am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the lists be increasing in value rather than decreasing, such as 6, 8, 10, 11, versus 11, 10, 8, 6?

Since merge is static, there's no need to have a class with head1, head2, and newHead as members. These could all be local references to node in main, and merge() could return a reference to node instead of taking a third parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node head1 = new Node(6);
    head1.next = new Node(8);
    // ...
    Node head2 = new Node(2);
    head2.next = new Node(7);
    // ...
    Node newHead = merge(head1, head2);
```

For merge(), it's simpler to allocate one "dummy" node, and have a working reference to node that starts off as a reference to the "dummy" node:

```
    Node dummy = new Node;   // dummy.next will be the merged list
    Node merged = dummy;     // working reference
```

Then merge and advance through the two lists using merged.next. When done, return dummy.next. You'll need to check for head1 == null or head2 == null at the start. If head1 == null use head2 or vice versa. It won't matter if both are null.

Comment: Thank you ! helped me a lot to understand the mistakes that i keep making.